# How do I get the client IP of a Tornado request?

Tags: python, tornado

I have a `RequestHandler` object for incoming `post()`s. How can I find the **IP** of the client making the request? I've browsed most of `RequestHandler`'s methods and properties and seem to have missed something.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`RequestHandler.request.remote_ip` (from RequestHandler's instance)

you can inspect the response like:

```
...
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write(repr(self.request))
...
```

Comment: Documentation: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.remote_ip

Comment: it keeps giving me 127.0.01

Answer (score 36):

mykhal's answer is right, however sometimes your application will be behind a proxy, for example if you use nginx and UWSGI and you will always get something like `127.0.0.1` for the remote IP. In this case you need to check the headers too, like:

```
remote_ip = self.request.headers.get("X-Real-IP") or \
            self.request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-For") or \
            self.request.remote_ip
```

Edit Oct 17th, 2019: include the commonly used header `X-Forwarded-For` which is used by AWS load balancers amongst others.

Comment: remote_ip = x_real_ip or self.request.remote_ip

Comment: @itzhaki thank you for the suggestion, I updated my answer

Comment: @itzhaki @3k But documentation(http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.remote_ip) says "If HTTPServer.xheaders is set, will pass along the real IP address provided by a load balancer in the X-Real-Ip or X-Forwarded-For header". So `remote_ip` is atlast return from `X-Real-Ip` or `X-Forwarded-For` from the header.

Comment: @igaurav so I hope using simply `remote_ip` does work by now. my solution came from practice as I found it necessary in the past, `remote_ip` gave wrong result when I tried.

Comment: in my case, this method doesnot work as we have had to config apache servers for this

Comment: But if you're NOT behind that kind of proxy and use that logic, an attacker could forge the client IP address by sending the `X-Real-IP` header.

Comment: X-Real-IP, X-Forwarded-For, remote_ip all don't work for me, anything else?

Comment: where to put this `xheaders=True` ?