# Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS on AWS-ELB-Tornado

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tornado, amazon-ec2

I notice a lot of questions on this topic, but I haven't found any specifically for Tornado.

I have a Amazon EC2 Instance running behind a load balancer.  The HTTPS cert terminates at the ELB, both port 80/443 are directed to the same Tornado server port.

How do I force redirect HTTP to HTTPS traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider to add CloudFront (CDN) in front of your ELB, it has many benefits i.e. lower latency for your application, handling traffic spikes. 
If you would go for this, CloudFront has http to https redirect [feature](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/03/05/amazon-cloudront-announces-sni-custom-ssl/).

Comment: This seems like suites the purpose better than doing redirect at the server.  What (if any) are the downsides?

Comment: ClouldFront can cache content for any period of time, thus even if you find any cons it can be fixed by proper configuration specific to your application. 
It is additional cost. However, with CDN you will have less load on EC2 instances, thus you will pay less for EC2 and ELB.

Comment: There is available excellent presentation about Dynamic Content Acceleration (re:Invent 2013) using CloudFront. I encourage to watch it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiXRVHgQ_Gg

Answer (score 1):

You have to send a HTTP 301 or 302 with the new location, see [RequestHandler.redirect()](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.redirect) for details.

Answer (score 0):

[Enable xheaders](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/httpserver.html#tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer) and use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. That will tell you if the original request came in through http or https.

Also, see SO question [Retrieve browser headers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420886/retrieve-browser-headers-in-python).