# How do I get IP Addres in Python

Tags: python

Is there any way to get the IP address in pure python (not Django)?

I found the code bellow, but i do not have a Request object.

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Comment: IP of the user who made ​​the request service. This is a WebService in Tornado.

Comment: Did you ever think of maybe telling us that?

Comment: I want to determine the outside ip (non an local)

Comment: A simple google search provided this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110919/how-do-i-get-the-client-ip-of-a-tornado-request

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about your local machine a quick google search found this:

[Finding local IP addresses using Python's stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166506/finding-local-ip-addresses-using-pythons-stdlib)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are saying that you have a socket object that is the result of an earlier `accept` call.  If so, that socket object will have a `getpeername` attribute:

```
result = descriptor.getpeername()
```

If it's an IP socket the result will be the `(hostaddr, port)` pair.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the local IP adress using the socket module

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Comment: python3.4    I can only get `127.0.0.1`  by this way