# How do I get the client IP of a Tornado request from the WebSocket Handler?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110919/how-do-i-get-the-client-ip-of-a-tornado-request
```

Above link tells us how we could derive the Client IP for a Request Handler. What about while using a Websocket Handler?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand, do you need the remote ip from web-socketHandler?

Comment: Let's just say that i merely need a record of IPs of the users accessing via the websocket

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `class WebSocketHandler` extends `RequestHandler`

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
```

So, you can get the ip in this way:

```
class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        logging.info('Client IP:' + self.request.remote_ip)
```

Answer (score 4):

if you used nginx as proxy server, the situation will be a little more complex, there are two solutions:

**option 1: using self.request.remote_ip**
if you insist using this method, you need to configure both nginx and your tornado app.
step 1:  in nginx server block add either of fllowing lines:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

or

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
```

step 2: when creating tornado httpserver, add xheader option

```
server = httpserver.HTTPServer(application, xheaders=True)
```

then you can use **self.request.remote_ip** to get your remote ip address now

**option 2: get X-Real-Ip from HttpRequest headers**
following code will give you remote real ip directly:

`self.request.headers.get('X-Real-Ip', '')`